# rails form trying to get the posts path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I cant get the syntax of this correct I'm trying to include  :url => posts_path in the form_for section

```
<% form_for :post do |f| %>
<p>
<%= f.label :text %><br>
<%= f.text_area :text %></p>

<p><%= f.submit %></p>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this.  Like @meager, you want to call `Post.new`.  I usually do it in the controller, though.

**posts_controller.rb**

```
@post = Post.new
```

**view**

```
 <% form_for @post do |f| %>
   ...
 <% end %>
```

You can use a custom path if that's where you want to send the data.  So if you have a special case, you can make a route for it

**routes.rb**

```
get '/special', to: 'posts#special'
```

then you can have a form that says...

```
<% form_tag special_path do |f| %>
   ...
<% end %>
```

and the params will pass as you'd think.  Notice the `form_tag` instead of `form_for` though.

Comment: Submitting a form to a `get` route is a bit of a problem, and there's also no reason to drop `form_for` if you have an object. You can just use `form_for @post, url: special_path`.

Answer (score 2):

`form_for` expects an instance of a model, not a symbol:

```
<% form_for Post.new do |f| %>
...
<% end %>
```